# External Scan Vs Table Scan in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I wanted to understand which is faster external scan or table scan in snowflake. I think it is external scan but wanted to get a confirmation and also the reason behind that

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to Snowflake persistent tables vs. External tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TableScan operation is faster.

The ExternalScan operation represents access to data stored in stage objects and the TableScan operation represents access to a single table.

The execution time of such a node depends on several things, mostly commonly Remote Disk IO, Local Disk IO and processing.

The data transfer speed of Remote Disk IO should be the same, assuming they are both S3 (or similar.)

Stage objects are not not cached locally, so TableScan is always faster if caching is possible, since Local Disk IO is much faster than Remote Disk IO.

Typically the processing on a Scan node is negligible.

I expect performance be similar only in a scenario with no caching and where the stage objects are stored as compressed Parquet using 10-50mb partitions with a good key and good choices for column encoding.

Without such careful attention to the stage objects, I expect TableScan to significantly out perform ExternalScan because of partition pruning, byte-offset reads, automatic column encoding and other Snowflake automatic optimizations.